# Why doesn't setuptools support README.md?

Tags: python, markdown, restructuredtext

The doc says:

> All projects should contain a readme file that covers the goal of the project. The most common format is reStructuredText with an “rst” extension, although this is not a requirement.

`setup.py sdist` automatically packages `README.rst` but not with `README.md`. Is there anything special with Markdown format?

Where to put `README.md` if I want to achieve the same effect as `README.rst`? `package_data`, `data_files` or `MANIFEST.in`?

Comment: MarkDown .md format arised after the python setuptools toolkit became popular. Simple as that

Comment: @agg3l It's been several years and shouldn't the pypa people be aware of it already? I'm wondering whether the usage of .md is discouraged for python package readmes. But the doc says it doesn't have a requirement.

Comment: I won't bet my finger on it, but - MarkDown is about rendering text to HTML representation, first place.
Nor python nor some install package knows nothing about web (i.e. internet) - just because it's focused on installation and generic OS support.
There is no much reason to introduce MarkDown support, simply because it's not related to primary task anyhow.
Still, it's opensource - you're free to implement this feature and help the community yourself ;)

Comment: ReST is part of docutils and the markup language used for documentation of Python itself. It was also purpose built as a markup language for creating technical documentation whereas Markdown was created for writing prose. While I prefer Markdown, I have to admit that ReST is a better tool for writing documentation. I would be surprised if anyone deeply invested in Python would be motivated enough to actually add support for Markdown in the disutils library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does now.  Support was added in [version 36.4.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v36-4-0), released on 03 Sep 2017.